# Overriding initialize error test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a hard time understanding an error with ruby's open classes. Overriding a method in test environment (rails) causes an invalid arguments error on initialize. For some reason, overriding the new method solved the problem. Why?

My class:

```
require 'adwords_api'
require 'adwords_config'
require 'scanf'

class AdwordsHelper
  attr_accessor :adwords_id
  attr_accessor :campaign_id
  attr_accessor :adgroup_id
  attr_accessor :invalid_ops

  @@RETRY_INTERVAL = 3
  @@RETRIES_COUNT = 500
  @@config = 'adwords_api.yml'

  def initialize(args = {})
    self.adwords_id = AdwordsConfig.config[:master_account]

    return unless args.is_a?(Hash)
    args.each do |k,v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) unless v.nil?
    end
  end

  def set_budget(budget)
    @api = get_adwords_api
    budget_id = get_budget_id

    service = @api.service(:BudgetService)
    operation = {
      :operator => 'SET',
      :operand => {
        :budget_id => budget_id,
        :amount => {
          :micro_amount => budget
        }
      }
    }

    service.mutate([operation])
  end
end
```

Now in the test, I want to override one of the methods, because I don't want there to be communication with the actual adwords servers.

```
require "test_helper"
# FIXME override this in another file eventually
class AdwordsHelper
  def set_budget(budget)
    true
  end
end
```

Calling

```
AdwordsHelper.new(campaign_id: 1)
```

gives an invalid arguments 1 for 0 error.

Now, overriding the new function, solves the error.

```
class AdwordsHelper
  def self.new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate
    obj
  end
  def set_budget(budget)
    true
  end
end
```

Is overriding the method set_budget causing other quirks?

Comment: Is it possible your class isn't being autoloaded because `AdwordsHelper` is already defined in your test file? Try a `require_relative '../../app/classes/adwords_helper'` (or whatever the path is) just after your `#FIXME` comment.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it. I prefer this solution over the class eval solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
AdwordHelper.class_eval do
  def set_budget(budget)
    true
  end
end
```

`class AdwordHelper` will define the class when the original AdwordHelper is not loaded already, in which case the only method that exists in your class is set_budget. It wouldn't know about the initialize with one argument.

Whereas, if you use class_eval, it tries to load the file containing AdwordHelper class and then add the method set_budget to the class.

Comment: This works as well. Thanks. I prefer the solution mentioned by zach though as it feels more natural.